# incomprehensible performance improvement with openmp even when num_threads(1)

Tags: c++, openmp

The following lines of code

```
int nrows = 4096;
int ncols = 4096;
size_t numel = nrows * ncols;
unsigned char *buff = (unsigned char *) malloc( numel );

unsigned char *pbuff = buff;
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static), firstprivate(pbuff, nrows, ncols), num_threads(1)
for (int i=0; i<nrows; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<ncols; j++)
    {
        *pbuff += 1;
        pbuff++;
    }
}
```

take 11130 usecs to run on my i5-3230M when compiled with

```
g++ -o main main.cpp -std=c++0x -O3
```

That is, when the openmp pragmas are ignored.

On the other hand, it only takes 1496 usecs when compiled with

```
g++ -o main main.cpp -std=c++0x -O3 -fopenmp
```

This is more than 6 times faster, which is quite surprising taking into acount that it is run on a 2-core machine. In fact, I have also tested it with *num_threads(1)* and the performance improvement is still quite important (more than 3 times faster).

Anybody can help me to understand this behaviour?

EDIT: following the suggestions, I provide the full piece of code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <chrono>
#include <cassert>


int nrows = 4096;
int ncols = 4096;
size_t numel = nrows * ncols;
unsigned char * buff;


void func()
{
    unsigned char *pbuff = buff;
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static), firstprivate(pbuff, nrows, ncols), num_threads(1)
    for (int i=0; i<nrows; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<ncols; j++)
        {
            *pbuff += 1;
            pbuff++;
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    // alloc & initializacion
    buff = (unsigned char *) malloc( numel );
    assert(buff != NULL);
    for(int k=0; k<numel; k++)
        buff[k] = 0;

    //
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point begin;
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point end;
    begin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();      
    //
    for(int k=0; k<100; k++)
        func();
    //
    end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto usec = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end-begin).count();
    std::cout << "func average running time: " << usec/100 << " usecs" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you memset the entire memory region to zero before the loop?

Comment: Does OpenMP do Vectorization?  That is about 3x to 4x.

Comment: You need to measure many times to eliminate noise effects. Previous implication of cache is also good. And no, adding OpenMP flags should not enable _additional_ autovectorization.

Comment: Looking at the assembly is prudent.

Comment: I agree with @Jeff. I ran your code in Virtual Box and I get widely varying results with in a factor of 10 for different iterations.

Comment: The timings provided are mean times, in addition I repeated the test several times and the numbers are coherent, so noise effects should not be an issue. For the same reason cache effects should affect identically to both.

By the way, I have tested it initializing the memory region to zero and the results are identical.

Comment: How are you timing this? You only provided a code fragment. Can you provide more of your code and how you time?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the described behaviour with gcc 4.9.2 on Ubuntu. Both versions, with and without OpenMP run in 5ms when executed single-threaded.

Comment: Ignoring the timing issues, doesn't `*pbuff += 1` need to be atomic (atleast when you use multiple threads)?

Comment: @mastov, that's why the OP needs to provide more code (along with the assembly ) rather than just a fragment.

Comment: The full code was added following your suggestions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer, as it turns out, is that `firstprivate(pbuff, nrows, ncols)` effectively declares `pbuff`, `nrows` and `ncols` as local variables within the scope of the for loop. That in turn means the compiler can see `nrows` and `ncols` as constants - it cannot make the same assumption about global variables!

Consequently, with `-fopenmp`, you end up with the huge speedup because *you aren't accessing a global variable each iteration*. (Plus, with a constant `ncols` value, the compiler gets to do a bit of loop unrolling).

By changing

```
int nrows = 4096;
int ncols = 4096;
```

to

```
const int nrows = 4096;
const int ncols = 4096;
```

**or** by changing

```
for (int i=0; i<nrows; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<ncols; j++)
    {
        *pbuff += 1;
        pbuff++;
    }
}
```

to

```
int _nrows = nrows;
int _ncols = ncols;
for (int i=0; i<_nrows; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<_ncols; j++)
    {
        *pbuff += 1;
        pbuff++;
    }
}
```

the anomalous speedup vanishes - the non-OpenMP code is now just as fast as the OpenMP code.

The moral of the story? Avoid accessing mutable global variables inside performance-critical loops.

Comment: I can reproduce your results. This is bizarre. The assembly is very different.

Comment: Your answer seems to be the good one. I have added the const modifier suggested and now the non-OpenMP version is as fast as the OpenMP one. Thank you very much!

Comment: You have given a solution to the OPs problem. But as far as I can tell you have not explained WHY this is necessary. Can you answer that? Maybe it's obvious to you but not to me. Using non constant local variables is not a problem so why is it a problem with global variables? It seems to be some sort of pointer aliasing.

Comment: Using `static` e.g `static int nrows = 4096;` also fixes the problem. I guess it's the external linkage that's the problem.