# Unexpected performance with global variables

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, global-variables

I am getting a strange result using global variables. This question was inspired by [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30656012/incomprehensible-performance-improvement-with-openmp-even-when-num-threads1). In the code below if I change

```
int ncols = 4096;
```

to

```
static int ncols = 4096;
```

or

```
const int ncols = 4096;
```

the code runs much faster and the assembly is much simpler.

```
//c99 -O3 -Wall -fopenmp foo.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int nrows = 4096;
int ncols = 4096;
//static int ncols = 4096;
char* buff;

void func(char* pbuff, int * _nrows, int * _ncols) {
    for (int i=0; i<*_nrows; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<*_ncols; j++) {
            *pbuff += 1;
            pbuff++;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    buff = calloc(ncols*nrows, sizeof*buff);
    double dtime = -omp_get_wtime();
    for(int k=0; k<100; k++) func(buff, &nrows, &ncols);
    dtime += omp_get_wtime();
    printf("time %.16e\n", dtime/100);
    return 0;
}
```

I also get the same result if `char* buff` is a automatic variable (i.e. not `global` or `static`). I mean:

```
//c99 -O3 -Wall -fopenmp foo.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int nrows = 4096;
int ncols = 4096;

void func(char* pbuff, int * _nrows, int * _ncols) {
    for (int i=0; i<*_nrows; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<*_ncols; j++) {
            *pbuff += 1;
            pbuff++;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char* buff = calloc(ncols*nrows, sizeof*buff);
    double dtime = -omp_get_wtime();
    for(int k=0; k<100; k++) func(buff, &nrows, &ncols);
    dtime += omp_get_wtime();
    printf("time %.16e\n", dtime/100);
    return 0;
}
```

If I change `buff` to be a short pointer then the performance is fast and does not depend on if `ncols` is static or constant of if `buff` is automatic. However, when I make `buff` an `int*` pointer I observe the same effect as `char*`.

I thought this may be due to pointer aliasing so I also tried

```
void func(int * restrict pbuff, int * restrict _nrows, int * restirct _ncols)
```

but it made no difference.

Here are my questions

1. When `buff` is either a `char*` pointer or a `int*` global pointer why is the code
   faster when `ncols` has file scope or is constant?
2. Why does `buff` being an automatic variable instead of global or static make the code faster?
3. Why does it make no difference when `buff` is a short pointer?
4. If this is due to pointer aliasing why does `restrict` have no noticeable effect?

Note that I'm using `omp_get_wtime()` simply because it's convenient for timing.

Comment: If the variable is a compile-time constant, then the compiler may make certain optimizations because it know the variable can't change.

Comment: Why pass the sizes by reference? You could simply pass them by value.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, that's clear, but i get the same result using `static` which just changes it to have file-scope instead of global scope. Also, if `ncols` was an automatic variable which was not declared constant the code would still be fast even if it's not declared constant.

Comment: If the variable is file-local, the compiler can analyze the [*translation unit*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29) and see that the variable doesn't change, and can apply the same optimizations. If the variable is not file-local, then the compiler doesn't know if it might be modified by some other translation unit.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, that makes sense. But why would another translation unit changing the variable matter? All that maters is the value it had when it enters the loop? I could understand that if another thread could change the global variable during the loop then it would be a problem.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, why would making `buff` automatic make a difference? `ncols` is still global and could be changed by another translation unit. The same goes for using a short pointer. `ncols` could still change even when the pointer is short.

Comment: Because you pass the arguments as *pointers*. If you passed the arguments by value instead, then the values will be *copied* and the arguments in the function can't be changed from the outside. Because you pass as pointers, there might be other threads of execution which modifies the values, and those values will then be in the function as well.

Comment: Same thing with the regards to the `buff` variable, if it's global some other thread might modify it. And while the compiler doesn't really care about threads (or even knows about them) it do know that a variable might be modified by external sources and generate different code then.

Comment: Another explanation could be that static and global could be mapped into different L2 cache pages.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, I don't see why the compiler won't optimize this unless it assumes another thread could modify the global variable. If this was on a single threaded system the compiler could produce code just as efficient as if the global variables were constant. Assuming the global variables may change due to another thread is the only thing that makes sense to me.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, and I still don't understand why using `short*` makes the code always run fast.  Even with `short*` `ncols` could change due to another thread. What's special about `short*`?

Comment: @joop, let me make a correction. I don't get the same result passing by value. What I meant is I get the same result by using the global variable directly rather than passing it as a pointer. Passing by value will make a local copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some elements allow, as it's been written, GCC to assume different behaviors in terms of optimization; likely, the most impacting optimization we see is loop vectorization. Therefore,

> Why is the code faster?

The code is faster because the hot part of it, the loops in `func`, have been optimized with auto-vectorization. In the case of a qualified `ncols` with `static`/`const`, indeed, GCC emits:

> note: loop vectorized
>   note: loop peeled for vectorization to enhance alignment

which is visible if you turn on `-fopt-info-loop`, `-fopt-info-vec` or combinations of those with a further `-optimized` since it has the same effect.

---

> 2. Why does buff being an automatic variable instead of global or static
>      make the code faster?

In this case, GCC is able to compute the number of iterations which is intuitively necessary to apply vectorization. This is again due to the storage of `buf` which is external if not specified otherwise. The whole vectorization is immediately skipped, unlike when `buff` is local where it carries on and succeeds.

> 3. Why does it make no difference when buff is a short pointer?

Why should it? `func` accepts a `char*` which may alias anything.

> 4. If this is due to pointer aliasing why does restrict have no noticeable effect?

I don't think because GCC can see that they don't alias when `func` is invoked: `restrict` isn't needed.

Comment: You make a good point about vectorization. But your second point I don't think it's because GCC can compute the number of iterations when `buff` is local (since `ncols` may still be global and non-constant it can change). It's because it knows that `buff` is not changed externally.

Comment: @Zboson Indeed: it can't compute the number of iterations because it doesn't know if it's changed somewhere else, externally. Sorry if it was unclear in the answer.

Comment: @Zboson Can you show the specific assembly where it reloads `pbuff`?

Comment: I looked at the assembly again and now it makes more sense. For `char*` and `int*` it's vectorized or not-vectorized. For `short*` it's vectorized if the pointer is `const` or not but the code is nevertheless quite different but the performance is more or less the same. I guess the only missing piece is how to get GCC to tell it to vectorize for `int*` and `char*` even when it's not constant like it did for `short*`. Normally, I used `restrict` for that.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is not my code idea. I'm just trying to make sense out of it.

Answer (score 1):

A `const` will most likely always yield faster or equally fast code as a read/write variable, since the compiler knows that the variable won't be changed, which in turn enables a whole lot of optimization options.

Declaring a file scope variable `int` or `static int` should not affect performance much, as it will still be allocated at the very same place: the `.data` section.

But as mentioned in comments, if the variable is global, the compiler might have to assume that some other file (translation unit) might modify it and therefore block some optimization. I suppose this is what's happening.

But this shouldn't be any concern anyhow, since there is never a reason to declare a global variable in C, period. Always declare them as `static` to prevent the variable from getting abused for spaghetti-coding purposes.

In general I'd also question your benchmarking results. In Windows you should be using QueryPerformanceCounter and similar.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: The `static` keyword here means that the variable has file scope. Maybe the compiler makes it const since it's not modified in this code, and no other file can modify it. What's your opinion on that?

Comment: The solution is clear so I'm not concerned about how to avoid this (it was another OP who found this, I would not have used this code). I want to know WHY. As to the benchmarking why don't you try it yourself (I provided code) but you'll need to use GCC to compare apples to apples.

Comment: @Aif File scope = a variable declared outside any function body. The static keyword has nothing to do with that. Anyway, since the compiler can deduct that the static variable isn't modified, it can indeed likely optimize the code better, which was essentially what I wrote in the answer.

Comment: @Zboson The resolution of omp_get_wtime() is whole seconds... seems like a very crude way to benchmark code.

Comment: @Aif, it's clear to me why `static` is like `const` in this case. Using file-scope the compiler can determine that the variables is constant within the translation unit and since no other translation unit sees the variable it is effectively constant.

Comment: @Lundin, no, it's much more accurate than whole seconds. This is not an issue...move on.